# Why is this not proper regex for C++ ( regex exp ("[^,\s]*"); )?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm  using this line:

```
regex exp ("[^,\s]*");
```

and the C++ compiler is throwing an error. Using the example from the [cplusplus regex page](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/regex_match/)

i.e. `regex exp ("(sub)(.*)");`, I get no errors, but with the aforementioned line, I get the error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::regex_error'
  what():   regex_error
```

I'm trying to search for everything between spaces and commas, or between end of line or start of line and a space or a comma

---

Here's a script in case you want to test it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string itemString = "cheese, fries, drink, soda, coke";
    regex exp ("[^,\s]*");
    //regex exp ("(sub)(.*)");
    smatch matches;
    regex_match(itemString,matches,exp);
    for(int i = 0; i < matches.size();i++){
        cout << matches[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Here have a site that's usually not wrong](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex), unlike CplusPlus.com

Comment: Don't forget to escape regex when you paste them in C++ code!

Comment: @Adriano What do you mean? I just did `[^]` with `,` and `\s`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth The ECMAScript regex notation.

Comment: In C++ backslash prefix starts an escape sequence. In this case `\s` is not a valid escape sequence then behavior is undefined (compiler specific). It may be copied as is, removed all together or replaced with `s` (you may try to dump it to `cout` anyway you shouldn't rely on that behavior). Your regex should be `"[^,\\s]*"`.

Comment: @Adriano That's what I thought you might mean, but I tried that and it didn't work, although I don't see the `\``

Comment: Yes, StackOverflow uses bachslash to escape too! ;) Anyway solved that you have to fix your regex. To match a list of words separated by comma you may simply use `[\w]+`

Comment: @Adriano so `regex exp ("[\w]*");`? Because that gave me the same error. Also `regex exp ("([\w]*)");` did as well. In addition, replacing the `*` with a `+` did the same thing.

Comment: Escape that too, this regex `[\w]+` should be inlines in C++ source file as `"[\\w]+"`. For a more robust regex to split a comma separated list you may Google, I'm sure there are tons of examples.

Comment: I thought that as well, but still I get the same error. `regex exp ("[\\w]+");` or with the capture group, `regex exp ("([\\w]+)");` give the same error

Comment: Well, this page [http://gcc.godbolt.org/] gave me no syntax errors. I suppose it's worth mentioning I'm using MinGW 32bit on Qt 5.2.0 with `CONFIG += c++11` set in the `.pro` file, although as I said, the commented regular expression runs fine.